# How can I introduce modules to a legacy javascript project?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm a developer on a very large, many-page web app.  We're making a push to improve the sanity of our javascript, so I'd like to introduce a module loader.  Currently everything is done the old-fashioned way of slapping a bunch of script tags on a page and hoping for the best.  Some restrictions are:

- Our html pages are templated, inherited, and composed, such that the final page sent to the client brings together pieces from many different source html files.  Any of these given files may depend on javascript resources introduced higher up the chain.
- This must be achievable piecemeal.  The code base is far to large to convert everything at once, so I'm looking for a good solution for new pages, and for migrating over existing pages as needed.
- This solution needs to coexist on the same page as existing, non-module javascript.  Some things (like menus and analytics) exist on every page, and I can't remove global jquery, for instance, as it's used all over the place.

Basically I'd like a way to carve out safe spaces that use modules and modern dependency management.  Most tutorials and articles I've read all target new projects.

Requirejs looks like a decent option, and I've played with it a bit.  Its fully async nature is a hindrance in some cases though - I'd like to use requirejs to package up global resources but I can't do that if I can't control the execution order.  Also, it sucks to have the main function of a page (say, rendering a table) happen after secondary things like analytics calls.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you able to at least "modularize" your giant code base? For instance, can you divide up all the components your front end requires into different script tags? If so, you could gradually copy and paste all your scripts into UMD format which would, eventually, let you bundle them in a modern shiny tool like browserify/webpack https://github.com/umdjs/umd

Comment: Yeah, to a degree.  There are certainly groups of related pages for which it might make sense to bundle the javascript together.

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot to ask for. :-)  So here are my thoughts on this:

Usually, when you load a web page - everything that was being displayed is wiped so that the new incoming information does not interfere with what was already there so you really have only a couple of options (that I know of) where you can keep everything in memory in the browser and yet load new pages as needed.

The first (and easiest) way is to use FRAMES.  These are not used much anymore from what I've seen but each FRAME allows you to display a different web page.  So what you do is to make one frame use 100% and the second one use "*" so it isn't seen.  You can then use the unseen frame to control what is going on in the 100% frame.

The second way is to use Javascript to control everything.  In this scenario you create a namespace area and then use jQuery's getscript() function to load in each page as you need it.  I did this once by generating the HTML, converting it to hex via bin2hex(), send it back as a javascript function and then unhexing it in the browser and applying it to the web page.  If it was to completely replace the web page you do that and if it was an update to a web page you just inserted it into the HTML already on the web page.  Any new javascript function always attaches itself to the namespace.  If a function is no longer needed, it can be removed from the namespace to free up memory.

Why convert the HTML to hex and then send it?  Because then you can use whatever characters you want to us (like single and double quotes) and it doesn't affect Javascript at all.  There are fairly fast hex routines available on GitHub (see my toHex and fromHex routines).

One of the extra benefits of using getScript() is that it can sometimes also make it almost impossible for anyone to see your code then.  A fluke in how getScript() works which is documented.

Comment: I could have been clearer in my original description - we don't have whole html pages nested inside one another.  We have a base template that is inherited from by other templates, and so on, and there are other templates inserted into places to provide components.  There's only one <html></html> block, but it may be assembled from say 10 different html files.

getScript (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) looks like a useful util if we end up rolling our own here.

Comment: I'm looking at require.js now.  Looks interesting but other than the minify-ing of the used Javascript code - it basically is getScript() or just the jQuery AJAX calls.  Both of which (I believe) you can turn off the async part.  It is real easy to test if a function already exists and not to load it again.  If (as I said above) you use your own namespace then you just test if the function or variable is already defined and not load it again.  And even if you did load it again - it just overwrites what is already there.

Comment: Ok.  I just finished reading up on RequireJS and have to reverse my previous statement.  Look at: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/.

It talks about a command called shim. That will load things in in the order you present them and actually, after reading up on RequireJS I think it is a VERY useful set of routines.  I'm actually thinking of downloading and using it myself. :-)